# Customize start location for "insert Sitecore link" in rich text editor

Tags: richtext-editor

When my editors click the "insert Sitecore link" button in a rich text editor, I'd like to customize the starting point for the dialogs. For example, on Internal Link it starts at the top "/sitecore" item, and on Media Items it starts at the top of the media library. I'd like to have them start in a location I specify instead, at the very least start at the item I'm working with itself (like in a rendering, specifying the datasource location is ./ to have it relative to the datasource). Is this customization possible, and if so where would I specify those starting points?

Comment: You wanted this done unconditionally for all General Link fields on the site, right? Not just for 1 on a particular template?

Comment: It's not for a general link field but in a rich text field with the popup when you click "insert Sitecore link"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore even doesn't have the ability to configure starting location for the GeneralLink field type out of the box. You can ensure in it, but looking into the implementation of `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Link, Sitecore.Kernel`. Rich Text Editor button *Insert Link* uses the same dialog. It means that your solution should contain 2 steps:

1. Adding ability to use source for General Link.
2. Changing the behavior of the button *Insert Link*

---

**Part 1: Adding ability to use source for General Link.**

If you are using Sitecore SXA, then you are lucky, because SXA extends *General Link* field type. And you already have the ability to set *source* in your templates. And dialog will show only items that you have set using *query*.

If you don't use Sitecore SXA then you have 2 options:

1. Implement it by yourself using SXA implementation `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.CustomFields.FieldTypes.Link` as an example.
2. Follow [Sitecore General Link Field with Source Query](https://mickeyrahman.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/sitecore-general-link-field-with-source-query/) article to add the ability to set and use *source* field.

As an outcome of this step, you should have the ability to set query into *source* filed on your templates. And *Insert Link* dialog in the content editor should show only items that you set in your query.

---

**Part 2: Changing the behavior of the button *Insert Link***

You need to add a custom button to Sitecore RTE.
It should do exactly the same as what the current *Insert Link* button does, but with one addition. It should pass an additional URL parameter that will contain your query that points to the starting point. In the case, if you have SXA(or you will use SXA as an example), the URL parameter name is `ro`.